# Apache Hive LIKE 'string%' or substr?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm doing a query that counts % of https entries in a log. I can do it using `substr` or by using `LIKE 'https%'`:

1. `IF(url LIKE 'https%', 'https', 'http')`
2. `IF(substr(url, 1, 5) = 'https', 'https', 'http')`

Which of the two is better? I'm open to other alternatives.

The log itself is relatively big - several gigabytes.

Comment: seems like `LIKE` would be faster; Checking 5 characters vs a split operation and equality check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work functionally, In my opinion the first one is more readable.

However I suggest you run a test and see if there is any significant performance difference between the two. Otherwise, just pick your favourite.

Comment: It feels like LIKE is faster.

Comment: Maybe because `substr` instanciates a java String object while `like` just reads the first N characters... just guessing.